how to show textfield or 2 different component in react js?
I have two components in my demo application (Autocomplete and Text Field). I want to show only one component at any given time. The condition is that when the user uses SLASH (/), it will show the Text Field component; otherwise, it will show Autocomplete.
I tried like this
 export default function ComboBox() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setvalue] = React.useState('');
  const onchange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = event?.target?.value || newValue || '';

    setvalue(inputValue);
    setShow((prevState) => {
      const newState = inputValue?.includes('/');
      if (prevState !== newState) {
        if (newState) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('outlined-basic')?.focus();
          }, 10);
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('combo-box-demo')?.focus();
          }, 10);
        }
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {show ? (
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          value={value}
          onChange={onchange}
        />
      ) : (
        <Autocomplete
          disablePortal
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={top100Films}
          inputValue={value}
          // defaultValue={'abc'}
          onInputChange={onchange}
          sx={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pjhf7s?file=Demo.tsx
My initial rendering is correct; the Autocomplete component is visible. When the user enters the text 'the/', it correctly shows the Text Field component. However, when I remove the '/', it shows the Autocomplete component, but without the text automatically populating in the Autocomplete component.
steps to reproduce

Run application
Enter "the" in autocomplete it will show filter list
Enter "/" .. it will show text field with text "the/" . which correct.
Remove "/"
Autocomplete field is blank .. This is the issue

Expected output : after remove "/" it will show same behavior as point 2

Instead of trying to conditionally render one input or the other, and manage the tangled mess of input value and focused state between the two, I suggest you may be interested in using the freeSolo prop value on the AutoComplete component to allow users to enter any text they please. You can conditionally apply this prop based on the current input value.
Example:
export default function ComboBox() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: string) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        freeSolo={value.includes('/')} // <-- ***
        id="combo-box-demo"
        inputValue={value}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        options={top100Films}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


any other way ? to use different component...

any other solution achieve same thing without freeSolo

@user5711656 The problem I kept running into with toggling show between the two components was that AutoComplete wanted to reset the value state back to "" when it was toggled back on, even when not conditionally rendering it and trying to use CSS to just conditionally hide it visibly (so it remained mounted). Anything I tried to either use a single value state or synchronize two states between two inputs just too quickly became too messy. It could probably eventually be accomplished with enough manual logic, but that's not anything I'd want to maintain longterm.
